# Searching element in Matrix using linear search

Tags: python, nested-lists, linear-programming

The program return true for only first row in the matrix. My problem is it is not looping all the other rows. It also has to be It is a linear search starting from both directions; the first element and last element of each sublist.

```
def SublistSearch(mat, key):
    count = 0
    for i in mat:
        while count < len(i):
            if i[count] == key:
                return True, count + 1
            count += 1
        return False, count


mat = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]]
key = int(input('Enter a number you want to search: '))
result, count = SublistSearch(mat, key)
print('For matrix')
for m in mat:
    print(m)
print('========================')

if result == True:
    print(f'It takes {count} loop(s) to find {key}.')
else:
    print(f'Sorry {key} could not be found.')
```